# How do I offset a Normal UV in a Unity shader?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, shader

I have this shader which offsets a texture at a given speed (to simulate water flowing, lava, usual stuff). It works fine except for the normal texture which, for some reason, does not get offset even though I use the same code. Can anyone see why?  When applied to an object the main texture scrolls, but the normal remains in the same place.

```
 Shader "mrpmorris/Scrolling shader" {
     Properties{
         _MainTint("Diffuse tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
         _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
         _NormalTex("Normap map", 2D) = "bump" {}
         _ScrollXSpeed("X scroll speed", Range(-10, 10)) = 0
         _ScrollYSpeed("Y scroll speed", Range(-10, 10)) = -0.4
     }
     SubShader{
         Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
         LOD 200

         CGPROGRAM
         // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
         #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

         // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
         #pragma target 3.0

         fixed4 _MainTint;
         fixed _ScrollXSpeed;
         fixed _ScrollYSpeed;
         sampler2D _MainTex;
         sampler2D _NormalTex;

         struct Input {
             float2 uv_MainTex;
             float2 uv_NormalTex;
         };

         void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
             fixed offsetX = _ScrollXSpeed * _Time;
             fixed offsetY = _ScrollYSpeed * _Time;
             fixed2 offsetUV = fixed2(offsetX, offsetY);

             fixed2 normalUV = IN.uv_NormalTex + offsetUV;
             fixed2 mainUV = IN.uv_MainTex + offsetUV;

             float4 normalPixel = tex2D(_NormalTex, normalUV);
             float3 n = UnpackNormal(normalPixel);
             float4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, mainUV);

             o.Albedo = c.rgb * _MainTint;
             o.Normal = n.xyz;
             o.Alpha = c.a;
         }
         ENDCG
     }
     FallBack "Diffuse"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the normal map was actually rotating, but because I had set the tiling on the material on the Normal different from the tiling on the Main texture it was moving so slowly that it looked stationary.

Comment: Well... I didn't notice your self-answer so I made you a video as requested... see below comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, not sure why on your end it doesn't... BTW, I'd use the basic to get more control, like the following:

```
Shader "Custom/ScrollingShader" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NormalTex("Normap map", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _ScrollXSpeed("X scroll speed", Range(-10, 10)) = 0
        _ScrollYSpeed("Y scroll speed", Range(-10, 10)) = -0.4 }
        SubShader{
            Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
            LOD 200

            CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _NormalTex;
        fixed _ScrollXSpeed;
        fixed _ScrollYSpeed;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float2 uv_NormalTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed offsetX = _ScrollXSpeed * _Time;
            fixed offsetY = _ScrollYSpeed * _Time;
            fixed2 offsetUV = fixed2(offsetX, offsetY);

            fixed2 normalUV = IN.uv_NormalTex + offsetUV;
            fixed2 mainUV = IN.uv_MainTex + offsetUV;

            // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, mainUV) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;

            float4 normalPixel = tex2D(_NormalTex, normalUV);
            float3 n = UnpackNormal(normalPixel);
            o.Normal = n.xyz;

            // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
        FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code and my normal (bump) map remains stationary while the texture map scrolls. Are you sure the bump map is moving too? What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I'm on Unity 5.4.0f3 (64-bit), professional license, but I don't think this is the problem, maybe something is wrong with your setup or with your video drivers. Please do check those because the code does scroll both textures as it's supposed to do. If you want I can create a video for you in case you think that I'm kidding :)

Comment: I don't think you are kidding :)

Comment: Actually I would appreciate seeing a video, thank you!